# setuptools command for coverage.py

Tags: python, setuptools, coverage.py

What is the best way to create a command for setuptools which generates a code coverage report using [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage)?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Extending Distutils capabilities through extensions](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#extending-and-reusing-setuptools) and it is covered in the docs that I have linked. The basic idea is to give the command and the entr5y point for execution and the entry point should follow some of setuptools Component based terminology. I think, you are luck here, because someone has already tried successfully (  [Adding Test Code Coverage Analysis to a Python Project's setup Command](https://jeetblogs.org/post/adding-test-code-coverage-analysis-to-a-python-projects-setup-command/) ) integrating it for his project and you should be able to adopt it for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution which uses subprocess calls to the `coverage` executable. I assume you have a Python package called `mycoolpackage` which contains the code for which you want to measure test coverage, and you have a `mytests` package which exposes a `suite` function which returns the test suite.

First, create a `run-tests.py` file:

```
import os.path, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import unittest
from mytests import suite

unittest.main(defaultTest='suite')
```

then in `setup.py` create the following command and add it to the `cmdclass` argument of the `setup()` function.

```
class run_coverage(Command):
    description = "Generate a test coverage report."
    user_options = []    
    def initialize_options(self): pass
    def finalize_options(self): pass 
    def run(self):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.call(['coverage', 'run', '--source=mycoolpackage', 'run-tests.py'])
        subprocess.call(['coverage', 'html'])
```

Note that `coverage.py` does have an API which would allow you to accomplish this without using a subprocess call.

Comment: Adding a coverage command would really only be useful if you use the internal testrunner of setuptools. With this you can just as well just run the coverage command.